# SHELL: Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, build

I have the following script as a post build step in Jenkins:

```
#!/bin/sh
out=$(sudo curl http://192.168.33.19:8080/job/$JOB_NAME/lastBuild/api/json/json.tail.test  --user "jenkins:jenkins" | jq -r '.result')

res=$(echo $out|grep "FAIL")

if [ "$res" = "FAILURE" ]; then
    curl -X POST -d 'json={"RESULT":"'$res'","JOB_NAME":"'$JOB_NAME'","BUILD_NUMBER":"'$BUILD_NUMBER'"}' http://localhost:8888/jenkins.e2e.build.status
fi;
```

The build is SUCCESS but after executing the script, result becomes FAILURE with below console output in Jenkins:

```
+ out=SUCCESS
++ grep FAIL
++ echo SUCCESS
+ res=
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Xvfb stopping
Finished: FAILURE
```

What is the mistake I made in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input lines,

```
res=$(echo $out|grep "FAIL")
if [ "$res" = "FAILURE" ]; then
```

don't make much sense as you are trying to search for the string `FAIL` on a string `SUCCESS`, the `res` variable would obviously be empty,

```
echo "SUCCESS" |grep  "FAIL"
                                  #  Empty output returned
echo $?
1                                 #  Code '1' indicating failure error code of grep
```

in cases of string comparison like these, you need the exit code of the `grep` to determine a search success/failure.

Just use the exit code of `grep` *directly* and ask it run silently using the `-q` flag. The below conditional executes the `cURL` request when it finds the `FAIL` string from the earlier string output.

```
if grep -q "FAIL" <<<"$out" 
then
    curl -X POST -d 'json={"RESULT":"'$res'","JOB_NAME":"'$JOB_NAME'","BUILD_NUMBER":"'$BUILD_NUMBER'"}' http://localhost:8888/jenkins.e2e.build.status
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for this help. I am actually not that good in shell scripting and dont know many things on it. Thank you very much again.